# Cloning Databricks Notebooks from Bitbucket

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, databricks

The "**Revision History**" button in **Databricks** does the job of git push and commit to bitbucket perfectly. For collaboration, is there a way for my team mates to run **git clone** commands from **Databricks**?

Answer (score 0):

Your team mates might need to [configure a project](https://docs.databricks.com/projects.html#configure-a-project) in their Databricks workspace:

[image: https://docs.databricks.com/_images/clone-from-repo.png]

The project creation can be done by cloning an existing GitHub repository.

But, as commented, this is still in [Private Preview](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/release-types.html). So, you will need to request access to that feature.

Comment: @AlexOtt No I only pointed out part of the documentation which seemed relevant to the OP's question. since you are a Databricks solution architect, I would be interested to read your answer.

Comment: the main hint is "This feature is in Private Preview", so it's not generally available yet...

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. From what I understand this feature is in private preview would that be correct?

Comment: @KennethSingh Yes, you might need to apply for it.

Comment: @AlexOtt Any possibility of this private preview feature not becoming a permanent feature?

Comment: it should be released for public preview in a couple of weeks, can't say exact date right now